# Which is edge is longer?

Tags: modeling

I need to know which edge is longer only in the Right Orthographic.

[image: **enter image description here**].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just turn on showing of edge length, then any selected edges will display their length next to them:

[image]

There are also the MeasureIt tools which you can find in the view tab of the right side bar for more complicated cases (You may need to enable the addon to see the tab).